# I keep on getting errors in SAS

Tags: sas

I am just testing my SAS code it was working but now it is not. It says it is invalid.

Sample code:

```
data have;
 $ default $ student $;
cards;
(1) yes    yes   
(2) Yes    No   
(3) NO    Yes   
(4) No     No   
;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you wanted to have an INPUT statement in your code.  Also you need to have a variable name for that first string.

```
data have;
 input col1 $ default $ student $;
cards;
(1) yes    yes   
(2) Yes    No   
(3) NO    Yes   
(4) No     No   
;
```